# How to parse a JSON array inside a JSON object

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I am calling a web service which returns the following JSON when I use

```
dynamic jsonResult=    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content.ToString());
```

```
{
    {  "items": 
      [ 
       {     
     "category": "Category1", 
         "word": "stars",  
        "lemma": "star",    
     "url": "XY"   
       }  
      ]
    }
  }
```

I have create d class like the following:

```
 public class MyClass
    {
        [JsonProperty("category")]
        public string category { get; set; }
  
        [JsonProperty("word")]
        public string word{ get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("lemma")]
        public string lemma{ get; set; }
        
        [JsonProperty("url")]
        public string url { get; set; }
```

But I don't know how I can extract the list of json objects inside the json array.
I have tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
List<MyClass> list = 
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyClass>>(response.Content.ToString());
```

I need to extract the result as a list of `MyClass`.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That ain't JSON. Notice how it's wrapped by **double** curlies? `{{ ... }}`. Not legal.

Comment: @spender IMO, this is just a typo when adding the example

Comment: @Cid Assumptions cause wasted time. We shouldn't need to form "opinions" about what OP intended to communicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a root class. Your JSON contains a member named `items`

```
public class Root
{
    [JsonProperty("items")]
    public List<MyClass> items{ get; set; }
}
```

And then :

```
Root root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(response.Content.ToString());
```